# Count number of line matching given threshold value and return filename along with count

Tags: bash, loops, unix, awk

I have hundreds of folders with a file (file.tsv) containing four columns and I want to count number of lines matching given threshold on a column.

For example: file.tsv (all files contains same dataformat)

```
S.No age weight height  
1    25  65     175  
2    28  75     180  
3    24  72     179  
4    26  80     190
```

I can get the count using command:

```
for i in $(find . -name '*.tsv'); do awk '$3>=70' $i | wc -l ; done
```

It gives output like

> 3

but I need output like:

> file.tsv 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there...

```
    for i in $(find . -name '*.tsv'); do 
    awk 'BEGIN {ctr=0} 
         $3+0 >= 70 { ctr++ } 
         { next } 
         END { print FILENAME " " ctr }' $i; 
    done
```

By testing `ctr` in the END block you can also suppress the files not having a `$3 >= 70`, or having too few of them
(the edit corrected the flaw as pointed out in the OP's comment)

Comment: Dear Ronald, thanks for the suggestion, but i worry that this also counts header and always possible to get actual count+1(i.e header)

Comment: You're right. Change the expression `$3 >= 70` to `$3 + 0 >= 70`. This will prevent awk from converting 70 to a string if $3 isn't numerical.

Comment: fundamental shell: never do `for i in $(find...)` as it'll break for file names containing spaces, always do `find... | while IFS= read -r i` instead. Also, always quote your shell variables unless you have a specific purpose in mind by not doing so and fully understand all of the effects - use `"$i"`, not `$i`. Finally - the awk script contains a couple of commands that do absolutely nothing, it should just be `awk '(NR>1) && ($3>=70) {ctr++} END{print FILENAME, ctr +0}' "$i"`.

Comment: @EdMorton Our awk "scripts" are equivalent as far as there aren't any "headerlines" in the middle of the file. I personally like initialized variables, but that's a matter of taste. I also like to have an action for each input line, just to make sure I don't forget one. So I don't regard my script as inferior to yours.
It wasn't my intention to provide a production proof solution that works in every thinkable situation. It's only a schematic solution that can be extended to fit.

Comment: That's fine but it's doing some things you should never do and therefore IMHO it was worth pointing out. If you're going to add lines to awk just in case you forget something then you should probably finish the body with `{ print "Oh No, I forgot something!" | "cat>&2" }` to help you catch it but YMMV. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
for i in $(find . -name '*.tsv'); do echo -n "$i: " ; awk '$3>=70' $i | wc -l ; done
```

This is basically YOUR solution with just the filename printed adding a simple `echo -n "$i:` before awk.

I would implement it in a slightly different way:

```
find . -name '*.tsv' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} awk '{if($3 >= 70) { count++ ;}} END{print FILENAME,count}' {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Al you need is:

```
find . -name '*.tsv' |
xargs -n 1 awk '(NR>1) && ($3>=70){ctr++} END{print FILENAME, ctr+0}'
```

If your file names can contain newlines then add `-print0` to the `find` and `-0` to the `xargs`.